# iPhone:UISearchbar issue

Tags: iphone

Hello Friends,

I have add UISearchbar programmatically in my app for searching functionality but I facing issue is that I want to differentiate between NSString & NSNumber in UISearchbar so give me any idea or link to develop this functionality.

```
-(void) searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    NSLog(@"searchBar textDidChange");
    NSString *searchTextField = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[searchText stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]]];
    NSLog(@"Search Text String:--->%@",searchTextField);
    if ([searchTextField isEqualToString:@""]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"Remove searchData");
        [self.searchData removeAllObjects];
        [self.searchTableView reloadData];
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

UISearchBar will give you an NSString `searchText`. If your data that you to search trow is NSNumber you can simply create an NSNumber object from NSString.

Use [intValue](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/intValue) method to get the int form string. Pay attention to the case when your string is @"0" because intValue will return an int equal to 0 when the string is @"0" and also when the string does not begin with a valid decimal.

Comment: developing search using zipcode or country so I want valid zipcode otherwise display alertview so I want to get searchtext is digit or string any idea???